# Cloud9 throws error when spawning child process, is there a workaround?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloud9-ide

Confirmed by FAQ http://support.cloud9ide.com/entries/20862101-cloud9-throws-an-error-when-i-run-code-that-spawns-a-child-process-why cloud9 does not support spawning child processes in a shared environment. Is there a workaround to this?

Or can you just no longer use cloud9 if you need to spawn child processes? Seems like there must be some way for this to work?

Comment: I doubt it. I played with cloud9 for a while a few months ago but eventually dropped it - it's almost useable but it has too many issues like the one you bring up

Answer (score 0):

The only way (at the moment) to do this is by installing Cloud9 locally (see [GitHub page](http://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9)).

**edit** Cloud9 now has resolved this problem by providing a VM per project.